# Identical code behaving differently from Android (kotlin) and AndroidTest

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, rsa

I am trying to run the following code from test and from regular android run,
the following code runs correctly and manage to run from test but returns a different value from a regular run:

```
val privateKeyStr1 = "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"
val cipherText = "TWN1xaX+rjcdQ2vgnbMdv/y7VPMj35qvHgm1U1HeYK6X1pTJCHq4PSLaJUtndZmIIUxWvaU/hKimX0MbFfgKM3JZYGV8jsNv3bp/7HBAfs1CPz7UqjrwRF3h8FiN7EUYEB9D89JMqVp9/WgOXOu/NLGhNNS3ESYAA8bFyXDgDBpJVzPX/Qilv/OIp7T/nGPO4lXIAFsQtpf5A8R8N/sSssB3urZLkm9zTc2fyWZMUH6AD08+/UYtVp41Tf3bp6qIZZvrtfo44HWgOmPBxx+WGq0PVUVMDkXsmoIPQtUFRObfwTS8r0+reBDKAVfJgtxZRGqXbmsAK9KA4MlAoe67lA=="
val kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
val decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyStr1)
val privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decoded))
val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA")
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)
val plainText = String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText)))
print(plainText)
```

from test it returns:
"hello" (as expected)

from android it returns:
�5J�o���5ټ���s{���,A|R��2��guPЪ(t��g3��B�>�|O��<�ρu��;�9sa=��#\W�t�����~!n���ނ��m�B�Ǻ�*���K��V����s� ��Sÿ��<޴)9����* �J)��>�d���x��g&�4C�(~F���f��f�7}
�ز�����    �����
���
�o��D4���7  [�1h�*�nv4�Pޗ
�
ZE{`�Πhello

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the padding has not been removed. Possibly the specification `RSA` falls back to different defaults. Try a full specification with `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` or `RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding` instead of `RSA` in `Cipher.getInstance(...)`.

Comment: I tried doing so but I got some kind of an error: 
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding KeyFactory not available

and java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding KeyFactory not available

any Idea why the code behaves differently from test and not from test ?

Comment: Try the change regarding `Cipher` and _not_ `KeyFactory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to initialize the cipher instance as the following:

```
val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
```